# How to connect remotely to WD Book Live Duo using nfs?

Tags: ssh, firewall, nfs, debian

Connection in local network works perfect.
I use `nfs://192.168.0.10/nfs` to connect locally.

If I connect from internet I use static IP:

```
nfs://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/nfs
```

In this case it doesn't work and even doesn't respond.
I also tried to use UDP port to connect:
    nfs://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2049/nfs

Is WD has some firewall? Why I cannot connect remotely?

This is my access.allow file:

```
lockd:ALL
portmap:ALL
statd:ALL
mountd:ALL
rquotad:ALL
```

access.deny is empty.

At the same time ssh works perfect remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either their is a firewall blocking the connection (maybe ufw), but it is probably port forwarding that needs to be setup. To check if ufw is running

```
sudo ufw status
```

If the firewall is running disable the firewall as a test and try again

```
sudo ufw disable
```

If after the firewall is down and everything works, we just need to open up the ports on the firewall and try again.

```
sudo ufw allow 2049
sudo ufw allow 111
```

Now try again. If it is still not working we may have missed a port (so you may want to look into what ports nfs uses and open them up if we missed any)

If that's not your issue, then it's port forwarding. You will need to open port 2049   and 111 on the router so that outside connections get forwarded to the right computer. Each router has it's own way of doing it, but usually it is pretty straight forward. Search for "Your router make/model Port Forwarding".

Your basically telling your router to forward all connection requests to 2049 and 111 to the ip address of your nfs server. When your connected locally, the router is able to figure out everything on it's own, but over the internet- the forwarding needs to be setup. Again, if you have further issues, there may be other ports that need to be forwarded to work. Just remember to forward them to the IP address of the nfs server.

Comment: ufw doesn't exist. I also forward ftp and ssh to internal IP. And it works good for these protocols. I tried to forward 2049 and 111 - still doesn't accessible outside. May be to change localhost on external IP in /etc/hosts?

Comment: I still think it's a port forwarding issue. Does rpcinfo -p | grep nfs return other ports?

Comment: or it's a iptables issue, but I am not that familiar with iptable rules.

Comment: It has only 2049 port (added to post)